# Кривая в цилиндрической системе координат, какие задать параметры?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть кривая заданная в цилиндрических системах координат, нужно отрисовать, но это уже мелочи.

r = exp(a * t)

fi = b * t^2

z = sqrt(-t)

Переходя к декартовым у меня вышло

x = exp(a * t) * cos(b * t^2)

y = exp(a * t) * sin(b * t^2)

z = sqrt(-t)

на что влияют коэффицента a и b которые по идее константные и что это за фигура? как изменяется t

Пока что выходит что то такое
[image: Пример]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так t от минус бесконечности и до нуля :)

Comment: https://bit.ly/3HJOfaU Что-то такое...

Comment: Спираль сужающаяся к оси z и закручивающаяся всё быстрее

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, понимание начало приходить

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, разобрался, получилосб +- то же что и на вольфраме